# Browser Not Showing CORS headers from AWS CloudFront but headers available through Curl

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

am streaming videos using s3 and cloudFront , i configured the CORS on my s3 bucket as the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>DOMAIN</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

also i added forwarding the origin header using the CloudFront Distribution whitelist but still i cant find the headers in the response headers.

but when i curl the same url i see the headers , am i missing something ?

cheers,

Comment: It looks like RFC violation of having specific domain and  * on AllowedHeader. Try AllowedHeader with the specific headers and verify. From the browser, it will make two makes for CORS. First will be the options and then the actual method call. OPTIONS will give more info about the headers allowed.

Comment: @Kannaiyan you're almost correct about `<AllowedHeader>` but the CORS configuration is interpreted dynamically by S3.  Using a `*` here will cause S3 to craft a valid CORS response that will *explicitly* allow any AWS-recognized headers the client indicates will be used.  The response is customized from the request; it won't be `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` with this configuration.

Comment: If you added the setting to forward the `Origin` header, but didn't do an [invalidation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) after that, this could be your problem.  Your browser may be hitting a different CloudFront edge than curl is contacting. Create an invalidation request for `/*` and wait for it to complete, then retest.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `Origin`, you need to also add both `Access-Control-Request-Headers` and `Access-Control-Request-Method` to the whitelist of headers. Then, remember to create invalidation and wait a while.

Now, For the given same URL request will be cached based on the combination of `Origin` * `Access-Control-Request-Method` * `Access-Control-Request-Headers`.

Using `curl` to test your CORS rules. If `www.example.com` is the origin you allowed, then the following output should include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com`.

```
curl -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -H 'Origin: http://www.example.com' --head
```